# WARNING conda.gateways.disk:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

i have this error when i try to install pytorch in my environment, i have found the file that i need to delete but, which one of the four files do i delete?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Di you use both pip and conda for installing packages ?

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck with the same problem. What I was doing wrong was I created one environment and installed packages using `pip install` while inside another environment I was trying `conda install`

The fix which worked form was to let conda itself remove unwanted files. This can be done using

```
conda clean --all
```

Comment: Your command works, but the original problem cannot resovle. *WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140): Could not remove or rename C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36\vcruntime140.dll.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)*

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when installing PyQtChart.  I received the following error:

> Executing transaction: - WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\topss2\Library\resources\icudtl.dat.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) done ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred
> while installing package 'conda-forge::qt-5.12.9-hb2cf2c5_0'. Rolling
> back transaction: done
>
> [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\topss2\Library\resources\icudtl.dat'
> ()

I was able to delete the file in question without rebooting.  I got lucky this time.

There are some analytics packages I use which do not have conda packages, so occasionally I have to use pip.  As I am doing development work, I don't always know in advance when I will need a Python package that only has a pip-formatted package, so I occasionally use conda after using pip.  I am usually too lazy to rebuild a new environment every time I "dead-end" a conda environment.  There is a way to roll back a conda environment if a pip package corrupts it, but that is not recommended.  Interoperability between conda and pip is still an experimental feature, but it is improving.  See the following link for more information: [conda-pip interoperability](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html?highlight=pip%20package%20installer#)

Does anyone know of a package to simply convert a pip package to a conda package?  This would make my life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message when installing OpenCV

> Executing transaction: \ WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140): Could not remove or rename C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Library\resources\icudtl.dat. Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)

I was able to resolve this issue by closing Spyder while installing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while cleaning up unused packages. It was more to do with Permission issue in my case. I resolved it by opening Anaconda Prompt in **Run as Administrator** mode and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Inside conda environment, for example want removing environment named `py36`

run

```
conda remove py36
```

```
conda clean --all
```

see errors.
[image]

then delete

[image]

then

```
conda clean --all
```

Now it is ok.

[image]

**Conclusion:** Need also command `conda remove` also delete by hand in Windows Explorer.